# Facebook Offers API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create an application where, the offers will be fetched from my system and published on to my facebook page using facebook graph API but as per the facebook link below,it says corresponding to an offer, an add must be published along with it.

So is it possible to push & publish offers on Facebook or not?

Reference Link : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/offer/

Comment: What problems did you encounter when creating the offers? (see also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#offers )

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked contains [another link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/offers/#publish) which describes the process for creating offers trough the api. Basically you just make a post request to `/PAGE_ID/offers` with a page access token plus whatever arguments you want to pass.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although it's now been rewritten to the /nativeoffers endpoint.

https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2016/08/30/offer-ads-apis/